# multiple buttons in get request using django and image display

Tags: python, html, django

html:

```
<form action="/verif/" method="GET">
<table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="lightpink">
<tr>{% for item in d1 %}
<td>{{item.card_number}}</td>
<td>{{item.first_name}}</td>
<td width="200">
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }} {{card_number}}.jpg" width="100%"></td>
<td width="100px"><p><input type="submit" value="ACCEPT" name="a" />
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="DISCARD" name="d" />
</p>
</tr>{% endfor %}
```

in views.py:

```
def verif(request):      
    if 'a' in request.GET:
            print(request.GET['a'])
            aa=Students(status='accepted')
            aa.save()
            return response("dir.html")
        else:
            aa=Students(status='rejected')
            aa.save()
        return HttpResponse("rejected")
```

there is no error. but its not working.

when `get` method is changed to `post` method it works as get.

Comment: did you close your form `</form` ?

Comment: Also if you want many forms as for loop.Put it inside forloop

Comment: i need only one form. the contents from table should be displayed using for loop

Comment: Try to put `endfor` inside `<tr>` tag

Comment: @AlexLisovoy not working

Comment: @Surumi Can you describe more your problem? `its not working`, does not tell me anything.

Comment: @AlexLisovoy html page displays contents from table as html table format. Each row of the html table contains 2 buttons accept and discard. These are used to accept/discard corresponding records. 1st problem :when it accepts 'status' field in Students model updated as 'accpted. but its not working. there is no change. 2nd problem: it does not display image. Image name is set as primary key of table. ie, card_number

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` is not closed.So try this

```
<form action="/verif/" method="get">
<table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="lightpink">
<tr>{% for item in d1 %}
<td>{{item.card_number}}</td>
<td>{{item.first_name}}</td>
<td width="200">
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }} {{card_number}}.jpg" width="100%"></td>
<td width="100px"><p><input type="submit" value="ACCEPT" name="a" />
</p></td>
<p><input type="submit" value="DISCARD" name="d" />
</p>
{% endfor %}</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did? Why it should work? Why it didn't before?